# How to implement auto session timeout using Angular.js,PHP and Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, session

I need one help.I have a login module using Angular.js , PHP and MySQL. Here I need when user is not doing anything inside the site after `15mins` it will auto logout and session will destroy.I am explaining my code below.

```
$http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'php/Login/session.php',
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
     }).then(function successCallback(response){
         //console.log('session',response);
         $scope.userType=response.data[0].first_name+" "+response.data[0].last_name;
     },function errorCallback(response) {
        $state.go('/',{}, { reload: true }); 
     });
     $scope.logout=function(){
         $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'php/Login/logout.php',
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
     }).then(function successCallback(response){
         //console.log('session',response);
         //alert(response);
     },function errorCallback(response) {
         //console.log('session',response);
         //alert(response);
     });
     }
```

> logout.php:

```
require_once '../../include/dbconfig.php'; 
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
session_unset();
session_destroy();
if(session_destroy()){
    echo "User logged out successfully";
}else{
    echo "User could not log out successfully";
}
```

> session.php:

```
require_once '../../include/dbconfig.php'; 
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE user_id=". $_SESSION["admin_id"]);
$data = array();
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
    if($data){
    print json_encode($data);
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        print "session has destroyed";
    }
```

> dbconfig.php:

```
<?php
$lifetime=900;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "********");
mysql_select_db('go_fasto', $con);

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "*******", "go_fasto");
?>
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$lifetime=900;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();
```

here 15 min is eual to 900 sec...so mention the maxlife time to the session before starting...so after 15 min if no action performed then session will expire

Comment: @ Tabasum : I added your line in my `dbconfig.php` file.Will it be logout automatically after `15 mins` .I have updated my code please check this.

Comment: ya if ur control is going in db config den max time will be set....try not to perform any action till 15 min and check...